# How to break when a DLL is loaded in kernel debugger mode?

Tags: windbg

In user mode debugging, I usually break with the following command:

```
sxe ld Something.dll
```

I tried the same in kernel mode, but it is not working. Is there a different command?

Comment: would setting an unresolved breakpoint on the entry point work: `bu Something!_DllMainCRTStartup` or `bu Something!DllMain`?

Answer (score 5):

You will want to run:

```
!gflag +ksl
sxe ld Something.dll
g
```

You may also want to refer to [1], which discussing breaking into a process near boot-time using the above approach.

[1] [How do I debug a process that starts at boot time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319716/how-do-i-debug-a-process-that-starts-at-boot-time)

Comment: Works like a charm. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I'm trying to break into a DLL that is loaded as part of a scheduled task that happens at logon, but the kernel debugger never breaks in.

Answer (score 1):

While doing kernel mode debugging : using `sxe` you will be able to break ONLY for kernel mode binaries like *.sys file.

Not for user mode binaries like *.dll

If you share what you are trying achieve may be we can find some other way to achieve that !